# Java Paint Problem

Tags: java, swing, paint, jlabel

Ok I'm wondering why the code below will not display the JLabel.

MyPanel is getting added correctly to a JFrame and everything because it all displays but will not draw the JLabel. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
  private Root root;
  ...

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    root.paint(g2); 
  }
}

class Root {
  private Node1 node1;

  ...
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    node1.paint(g);
  }
}

class Node1 {
  ...
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    JLabel jtp = new JLabel();
    jtp.setLocation((int) x, (int) y);
    jtp.setSize((int) width, (int) height);
    jtp.setLocation(40, 40);
    jtp.setSize(40, 40);
    jtp.setText("Hello world");
    //jtp.setVisible(true);
    jtp.paint(g);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you don't add Components to a Container in a paint method as 1) you do not have absolute control when or even if a paint method will be called and 2) paint and paintComponent have to be as blazing fast as possible, and this is not the time or place to update a GUI.  3) Since paint is often called many times, you will be adding components many times to your container, and all out of your direct control.

Also, while you're adding a component into Root (whatever Root is since it doesn't extend JComponent, JPanel, or similar) in the paint method, the Root object is never added to anything else that I can tell, and so it makes sense that nothing "added" to a component that is not added eventually to a top-level window will be visible.

Bottom line: I think you need a gui re-design as your solution. If you tell us more about it we can help you with it.  Next we'll need to talk about use of layout managers and why setting absolute position and sizes of components is usually frowned on.

If anything I say is confusing, please ask for clarification, or if anything is wrong, please help me correct it!

Answer (score 2):

You should not create your `JLabel` inside the paint method - instead, create it once when initializing your MyPanel. Your label is kind of a *renderer* component for your nodes, which in principle is a good thing. You may look how the renderers for JTable, JList, JTree work.

In your case, don't set the location of your label (it does not change anything, since it's paint-method expects its graphics object to be oriented by its own upper left corner), instead translate the Graphics-context:

```
 Graphics copy = g.create((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
 jtp.paint(copy);
```

(Graphics2D has some more fancy methods for shifting, rotating, scaling the context, too.)

Other than this, I don't see any problems. Make sure your `Node1.paint()` method gets actually called by putting some System.out.println() in there.